# advise for managing and troubleshooting modules

Tags: 7

I think anyone using Drupal runs into this sooner or later. You're trying to get to some solution and you start adding modules. Then somethings start breaking. The last time I had this problem, I uninstalled and then reinstalled the modules by enable/reenable the check boxes on the module page.

This time I have a lot of new content types and views and wot wot, and I'm scared. (>_<) I don't know if I'll lose these bits. I've exported my views, I've dumped the database. But I'm still nervous. What advise would you give, or reassurance?

Comment: ooh. lookie, it took only four hours to remove...49 modules and reenable 21...in 11 passes of save... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking the module does not uninstall it, it is just disabled. The schema related to the module is only removed when it is first disabled and then uninstalled.

If disabling and then enabling can solved your issues then do it.

But disabling and then enabling a module would not do any thing harmful except to remove and then add its record in system table and would invoke few hooks like hook_menu, hook_theme etc.

Comment: That's about what happened. haha. One module did try to duplicate in api_branch table, but there remains only one entry in this table. I can't be sure if its the old entry or the new one since there is no date-like field.